# How to solve the error "Redirected when going from ' / ' to '/dashboard' via a navigation guard"?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

When I login with a user, it redirects me to the dashboard as expected. As soon as I logout and try to login again (even with another user, and WITHOUT refreshing the page) it gives me back this error in console:

[image]

I just want to redirect the user in the dashboard if authenticated, even when the page is not refreshed cause I did notice that if I refresh the page I can login without problems.

Help me if you can. Down here some code:

Login method

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions({
    attempt: "auth/attempt",
    }),

    submit(credentials) {
      axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", credentials)
        .then((res) => {
          // console.log(res.data);
          if (res.data.success) {
            
            this.attempt(res.data.token)
          }

          if (res.data.errors) {
            this.loginErrors = res.data.errors;
          } else {
            this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' })
          }

          
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (
            err.name !== "NavigationDuplicated" &&
            !err.message.includes(
              "Avoided redundant navigation to current location"
            )
          ) {
            
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
    },
  },
```

dashboard path in the router

```
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent,
            beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
                if (!store.getters['auth/authenticated']) {
                    return next({
                        name: 'home'
                    })
                }
                next()
            }
        },
```

attempt action in vuex store

```
async attempt({ commit, state }, token) {
            if (token) {
                commit('SET_TOKEN', token)
            }

            // se non c'è
            if(!state.token) {
                return
            }
            
            try {
                await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user')
                    .then(res => {
                        commit('SET_USER', res.data)
                    })
            } catch (e) {
                commit('SET_TOKEN', null)
                commit('SET_USER', null)
            }
        },
```

others from vuex

```
namespaced: true,
    state: {
        token: null,
        form: null,
    },

    getters: {
        authenticated(state) {
            return state.token && state.form
        },

        user(state) {
            return state.form
        },
    },

    mutations: {
        SET_TOKEN(state, token) {
            state.token = token
        },

        SET_USER(state, data) {
            state.form = data
        },

    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: the call to `attempt()` should be awaited, otherwise `this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' })` (and therefore the guard function on the `/dashboard` route) will be called *before* the call to the `/api/user` API has completed:

```js
    submit(credentials) {
      axios
        .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", credentials)
        .then(async (res) => {
          // console.log(res.data);
          if (res.data.success) {
            await this.attempt(res.data.token)
          }

          if (res.data.errors) {
            this.loginErrors = res.data.errors;
          } else {
            this.$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' })
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (
            err.name !== "NavigationDuplicated" &&
            !err.message.includes(
              "Avoided redundant navigation to current location"
            )
          ) {
            
            console.log(err);
          }
        });
    },
```

---

[`next` is a function that should be called exactly once](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) (*not* returned).
Try changing the code in the router to:

```js
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            name: 'dashboard',
            component: DashboardComponent,
            beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
                if (!store.getters['auth/authenticated']) {
                    next({ name: 'home' })
                } else {
                    next()
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: I've tried this way before but it didn't work, same error message in console

Comment: If I use location.href = '/dasboard' it works, but obviously it will reload the page, not acting like an SPA

Comment: I also noticed that the call to `this.attempt(res.data.token)` is not awaited. Can you try to fix that?

Comment: You mean maybe to call this.$store.dispatch('attempt', res.data.token) instead?

Comment: However in the network the call to api/user is succesfull, so the attempt method should have been fired